# What kind of diploma is the protagonist supposed to get?

Tags: the-platform

In the Spanish movie *The Platform* the protagonist will get an accredited diploma once he finishes his time in this multi-level platform prison.

**But what kind of diploma is that?** Is there any information on that? It doesn't seem to be mentioned in the movie.

Comment: I believe the emphasis is that it's a shortcut to get something. One would need to study and pass courses to get a diploma. The people sent to the hole seem to be looking for an alternate route to get to it.

Comment: @MovieMe, yeah I believe it could be some kind of diploma of bravery or diploma of humanity study or diploma of psychology.

Comment: I think it helps with jobs? Or general progression in the world outside. Considering the technology of that floating platform, I'd say this is set well in the future.